# Getting rid of NA values in R when trying to aggregate columns

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, na

[image: df]

[image]

I'm trying to aggregate this df by the last value in each corresponding country observation. For some reason, the last value that is added to the tibble is not correct.

```r
aggre_data <- combined %>% 
    group_by(location) %>%
    summarise(Last_value_vacc = last(people_vaccinated_per_hundred)
aggre_data
```

I believe it has something to do with all of the NA values throughout the df. However I did try:

```r
aggre_data <- combined %>% 
    group_by(location) %>%
    summarise(Last_value_vacc = last(people_vaccinated_per_hundred(na.rm = TRUE)))
aggre_data
```

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: It's hard to help you with a photo. Try using the function `dput()` on a subset of your data where the issue is reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
combined %>% 
    group_by(location) %>% 
    arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>% # or whatever
    summarise(Last_value_vacc = last(na.omit( people_vaccinated_per_hundred)))
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for your response. Ive tried your suggestion and still doesn't seem to work.```aggre_data <- combined %>% 
    group_by(location) %>%
    arrange(date) %>% 
    summarise(Last_value_vacc = last(people_vaccinated_per_hundred, na.rm = TRUE))
aggre_data```

Comment: I‘ve updated my answer too. If that not works, please tell as what you get (errormessage, unexpected results, or whatever).